# How can i upload files along with other model values in asp.net mvc using ajax?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, model-view-controller, upload

All the articles i've found talks about either uploading both files and text values using non-ajax form post, or uploading only files with ajax post requests. Is there a way to upload both files and text values using ajax post to mvc action where i can get model binding as well as Request.Files?

Answer (score 0):

After making some experiments, turns out the code doing this is also not that complicated:

```
var formData = new FormData($("form")[0]);

        $.post({
            url: "/Home/Upload",
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: formData,
            success: function () {
                alert("done");
            }
        });
```

The tricky part is the construction of FormData object. There's actually no need to manually add files and other text values, as long as all the inputs are inside a form tag.

Comment: One more trick, is that all the input elements inside the form tag must have a name attribute in order to get included in the form values.